# Netbeans / PHP - passing simple variable to another webpage

Tags: php, variables

I'm a complete noobie to PHP and trying to use it in Netbeans.

I've attached a screenshot of some coding that shows what i'm trying to do. Basically as the user clicks on the link

```
<A HREF="welcome.php?name=Kevin"> Hi, I'm Kevin! </A>
```

it transfers them to another web page using the name=Kevin as the variable in the welcome.php file.

For some reason the $name isn't recognising that it equals Kevin.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here, to learn more about passing variables to other pages: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $_GET["name"].

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php